# getting array of elements in my bootstrap modal . how do i show it in a organised way

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

```
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
<div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"> User Details</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
            {{selected | json}}
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">

  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/qRJrCcy0KElt2bT4HORc?p=preview
 getting { "name": "Mercury", "age": 0.4, "mass": 0.055, "descp": "it is the hottest planet" }  in the modal dialog.

```
how to make it organised in this manner;

name:
age:
mass:
descp:
```

Comment: You mean like this? https://plnkr.co/edit/xcGTx4o8Xmo4pfWk4fUj?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do with **`<li>`** tag

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <ul>
        <li> Age :  {{selected.age}}</li>
        <li> Name : {{selected.name}}</li>
        <li> Mass : {{selected.mass}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO WITH PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/hTvY6NRnZYmyaTn6rZl6?p=preview)**